# Include external library in webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

What is the syntax for including libraries in the bundle?
What I found in "LIBRARY AND EXTERNALS" for the documentation is this:

- depends on "jquery", but jquery should not be included in the bundle

What do I need to do if i want to do this instead:

- depends on "jquery", and jquery should be included in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can include it using [**Provideplugin**](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
}),
```

Comment: Is it able to resolve if I have the jquery source and use that ? Like in a path 
`lib/jquery/src`

Comment: You can do install jquery as a node module

Comment: yes, that works. But I want to include a custom build of jquery